# TFS2015 Build fails on all Command Line Commands with 'file not found'

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

In Team Foundation Server 2015 Build (on-premise), I'm having issues running simple command line commands. All Command Line tasks simply fail with the following error: "File not found: ".

Take for example the following build definition:

[image]

This is executed using an on-premise Build Agent and will fail with the following exception in the logs:

```
BUILD FAILED
2016-01-20T12:04:47.5127709Z ##[warning]Filename doesn't indicate a full path to a executable file.
2016-01-20T12:04:47.5127709Z Executing the following commandline. (workingFolder = D:\_work\2\s)
2016-01-20T12:04:47.5127709Z date 
2016-01-20T12:04:47.5127709Z Error message highlight pattern: 
2016-01-20T12:04:47.5127709Z Warning message highlight pattern:      
2016-01-20T12:04:47.5439748Z ##[error]File not found: date
```

Of course this is a simplified example where I simply want to output the current date using the `date /t` command. But the same problem occurs with all general command line commands which I've tried, such as `dir`, `time`, `path` etc. The [MSDN does not provide any troubleshooting info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/utility/command-line) on it, other than that the tool executed must reside in the PATH variable.

The issue is not specific to one build definition or repo; it can be reproduced on others as well.

The builds run as the built-in **svc_tfsbuild** account.

I'm perhaps thinking this is either a simple setting, or - wildly guessing - an issue related to rights, but cannot find any documentation where to look or what to check. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears this is a [known issue on MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1855910/-command-line-task-doesnt-find-copy-or-del-commands) as well.

In short a MSFT mentions the following:

> Commands that are built-in to command prompt don't work. Anything resolvable based on your PATH/PATHEXT will work.

In the comment from 27 Oct, 2015 it is stated that this will be fixed in the next sprint. The mentioned workaround for now is simply executing **cmd.exe** first and provide the rest as arguments.

Using the example from the original question this would lead to:

```
Tool: cmd.exe
Arguments: /c "date /t"
```

And I can indeed confirm this works.